# Dúvida com tomada de decisão

Tags: java

Meus queridos, tenho o seguinte código:

```
  public static void questionTwo(){
    String back = "";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Questao 02: ");

    while(!back.equalsIgnoreCase("N") && !back.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
      System.out.println("TO DO");

      System.out.println("Deseja executar essa questao novamente? [Y/YES || N/NO]");
      back = scan.next();
    }
  }
```

Até aí funciona OK, assumindo que o usuário não seja um retardado.
Mas vamos supor que ele seja e digite algo diferente de Y/YES ou N/NO

Como faço para retornar para o `System.out.println("Deseja executar essa questao novamente? [Y/YES || N/NO]");` caso ele digite outra coisa além do que foi proposto sem repetir o que está antes disso dentro do `while`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
private static boolean estaDentro(String resposta, String... alternativas) {
    return Arrays.asList(alternativas).contains(resposta.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
}

public static void questionTwo() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    repeteQuestao: while (true) {
        System.out.println("Questao 02: ");
        System.out.println("TO DO");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Deseja executar essa questao novamente? [Y/YES || N/NO]");
            String digitado = scan.nextLine();
            if (estaDentro(digitado, "N", "NO")) break repeteQuestao;
            if (estaDentro(digitado, "Y", "YES")) continue repeteQuestao;
            System.out.println("Não entendi o que você quis dizer, tente novamente.");
        }
    }
}
```

Coloque também, esses dois imports no começo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
```

O método `estaDentro` verifica se a string do primeiro parâmetro (`resposta`) é uma das alternativas passadas.

Temos dois `while`s. A única forma de sair do `while` externo (chamado de `repeteQuestao`) é ao responder `N` ou `NO`, o que fará um `break` neste laço ser executado. Se o usuário responder `Y` ou `YES`, o `continue` no laço externo será executado, o que fará a pergunta ser repetida. Qualquer outra resposta vai fazer o `Deseja executar essa questao novamente?` ser repetido quantas vezes forem necessárias sem que a questão inteira seja exibida até o usuário deixar de ser retardado (de acordo com a sua definição).

O truque é que estou dando um nome ao laço `while` externo para poder me referir a ele em um `break` ou `continue` posterior. Essa é uma característica da linguagem Java que pouca gente conhece, mas que é muito útil em situações como essa.

Comment: Victor, e isso mesmo, porem o que estou a procura seria mais ou menos um filtro.
Imagine se o usuario digite "sair" ou "continuar" por exemplo? A ideia era retornar uma mensagem do tipo; "Opção invalida! \nDigite Y pra continuar e N pra sair"

Entendeu mais ou menos o que eu quis dizer?

Comment: @Lucas Editei a resposta. Acrescentei um `System.out.println` no final do `while` interno.

Comment: Eu venho do C#, muitos anos parado. Mas não me recordo de ter os comandos Break e Continue. Não consegui entender completamente o uso dele, mas fiquei maravilhado com o que você fez!